# Magento enterprise edition indexing

Tags: magento

Does magento enterprise edition needs cron to be set in order to run Indexing the following process.

1. URL Redirects
2. Stock Status
3. Catalog Search Index
4. Product URL Rewrites
5. Category URL Rewrites
6. Catalog Category/Product Index
7. Catalog product price

I have flat catalog for category enabled, but whenever I modify category attributes like meta data, the changes are not getting reflected in the front end. But whenever I disable flat catalog for category, the changes are reflected. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of configuring it in magento. One way will require crons to be set to run.

To configure it go to : System > Configuration > Advanced > Index Management

You can here configure if you wish the indexes to be updated on **save** or when **scheduled**

The on save process will slow down the update & creation of products. But as indicated will update every-thing when you modify a product in the Back office.

The scheduled uses MYSQL Triggers to detect changes and with the cron will update the flat tables that needs updating.